# Erro no botão de deletar

Tags: android

Boa Tarde, Fiz um método de delete no meu banco e chamei ele na minha activity, só que o meu problema é que quando clico no botão ele não acontece nada, e não me apresenta nenhum erro no LogCat, alguém saberia me ajudar?

DbHelper:

```
package Base;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NAME_BASE = "Resultados";
    private static final int VERSION_BASE = 1;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, NAME_BASE, null, VERSION_BASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sqlCreateTableResultado = "CREATE TABLE resultado("
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "TimeCasa TEXT,"
                + "TimeFora TEXT,"
                + "GolsCasa INTEGER,"
                + "GolsFora INTEGER"+")";

        db.execSQL(sqlCreateTableResultado);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String sqlDropTableResultado = "DROP TABLE resultado";

        db.execSQL(sqlDropTableResultado);

        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void insertResultado(Esporte resultado){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("TimeCasa", resultado.getNomeTimeUm());
        valores.put("TimeFora", resultado.getNomeTimeDois());
        valores.put("GolsCasa", resultado.getValorUm());
        valores.put("GolsFora", resultado.getValorDois());

        db.insert("resultado", null, valores);

        db.close();
    }

    public List<Esporte> selectTodosResult(){
        List<Esporte> listResult = new ArrayList<Esporte>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String sqlSelectTodosResult = "SELECT * FROM resultado";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectTodosResult, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Esporte onde = new Esporte();
                onde.setId(c.getInt(0));
                onde.setNomeTimeUm(c.getString(1));
                onde.setNomeTimeDois(c.getString(2));
                onde.setValorUm(c.getInt(3));
                onde.setValorDois(c.getInt(4));

                listResult.add(onde);
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();
        return listResult;
     }

    public void delete(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String sqlSelectTodosResult = "DELETE * FROM resultado";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectTodosResult, null);
    }

}
```

Minha Activity:

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import java.util.List;

        import Base.DbHelper;
        import Base.Esporte;

        import static android.os.FileObserver.DELETE;

public class ResultSimples extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lista;
    private Button apagar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_simples);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaTimes);
        apagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndeletar);

        apagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DbHelper dd = new DbHelper(ResultSimples.this);
                dd.delete(); // É necessário passar o parâmetro
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        DbHelper dbhe = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Esporte> listaResultPartida = dbhe.selectTodosResult();

        ArrayAdapter<Esporte> adp = new ArrayAdapter<Esporte>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaResultPartida);

        lista.setAdapter(adp);
    }


}
```

Obrigado...

Comment: O erro está na linha do `dd.delete();`

Comment: Nathan o `dd.delete();` esta sem o parametro, veja que ele pede um numero tipo long `public void delete(long id)`.

Comment: Então @GuilhermeNascimento poderia colocar dd.delete(1); que seria um tipo long certo? (nesse caso)

Comment: @Nathan depende, o ID tem que vir de algum lugar, jogar um numero aleatorio ali não fará sentido, o id tem que existir no banco

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, **`d.delete("resultado", "id = " + id, null);`** é uma **falha de segurança**. Você está permitindo um ataque chamando SQL Injection. Este terceiro parâmetro existe justamente pra isso, evitar SQL Injection. Mesmo que nesse caso em específico seja impossível de se praticar uma injeção, é melhor tomar cuidado e não acostumar a escrever sentenças SQL desta forma.

Então, este código deveria ser

```
public void delete(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase d = getWritableDatabase();
    if (id > -1) {
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(id) };
        d.delete("resultado", "id=?", whereArgs);        
    }
    d.close();
}
```

O problema apontado na pergunta é que o método `delete` dentro de `DbHelper`, pede como parâmetro um `long` e não está sendo passado nada

```
apagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DbHelper dd = new DbHelper(ResultSimples.this);
        dd.delete(PARAMETRO_AQUI); // É necessário passar o parâmetro
    }
});
```

Comment: Como é possível injectar SQL numa situação como essa?

Comment: O problema não é esse, @ramaral. É acostumar fazer desse jeito e acabar comprometendo outros lugares (ou até mesmo outras aplicações) onde realmente podem haver riscos de injeção. Não sei se você concorda comigo, mas, mesmo que inofensivo num primeiro momento, isso pode trazer alguns problemas futuros. Realmente me expressei (rápido e) mal na resposta, vou editar ***=)***

Answer (score 3):

O erro está no parâmetro que o método **delete** está recebendo

```
public void delete(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase d = getWritableDatabase();
    if (id > -1) {
        d.delete("resultado", "id = " + id, null);
    }
    d.close();
}
```

Ele está esperando um **long** e você não está passando nada, isso gera o erro.

Na hora de chamar o

```
dd.delete();
```

Você deve passar esse **id** junto ou retirar esse parâmetro lá do método.

---

**Update (Solução):**

Deixe o seu método dessa forma

```
public void delete(){
   SQLiteDatabase d = getWritableDatabase();
   d.delete("resultado", null, null);
   d.close();
}
```

E ai pode chamar o

```
dd.delete();
```

Comment: Mas se eu retirar esse parâmetro, como poderia chamar a função no banco de deletar a tabela quando clicasse no botão?

Comment: Esse *id* funciona como a cláusula WHERE no SELECT, se você quer deletar a tabela toda, então não vejo necessidade de passar um *id*, você pode passar como null e remover o parâmetro lá do método

Comment: @Nathan Coloquei um Update (Solução): na minha resposta pra você entender melhor.

Comment: ainda continua dando erro quando clico no botão...

Comment: O mesmo erro? Você tirou o IF também lá do método ou só removeu o parâmetro?

Comment: @Nathan Na minha resposta eu esqueci de colocar o d. antes do close, tem que ficar dessa forma: d.close();

Comment: o código java está certo... ele esta me dando erro no onclick vou editar a pergunta e dá uma olhada por favor

Comment: Pronto @Leonardo Dias

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47782/discussion-between-leonardo-dias-and-nathan).